# jquery - build pretty url from parameters

Tags: jquery, url, uri, clean-urls

jQuery has a `param()` function, I'm looking for similar functionality. I need to return a url in my object. For example:

```
url: function() {
  return this.baseUrl + '?' + $.param({page: this.page, perPage: this.perPage});
},
```

this will return a url in the form of `example.com/?page=1&perPage=5` or something similar. How can I form the url `example.com/page/1/perpage/5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own function:

```
function build(base, params) {
    for(var k in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            base += '/' + k + '/' + params[k];
        }
    }
    return base;
}
```

The only problem is that the order of the parameters is not guaranteed (which is not a problem for query strings but might be for this kind of URLs). You might also want to add a check if `base` already ends with a slash or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea :)

```
'example.com/?page=1&perPage=5'.replace(/[&=]/g,'/').replace('?','')
 .toLowerCase();
```

Comment: +1 interesting idea. The only problem could be if a question mark is part of a parameter value.

Comment: Absolutely, but that's the beauty of still using `.param` -- as `?` is a reserved character in a URL it will be escaped by jquery: `document.write($.param({'blah': 'lol?hi' }));`

Comment: Interesting. Because actually inside the query string, `?` does not have to be escaped (afaik). But nice to know that jQuery does escape it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Felix Indeed, URLs are very forgiving with reserved characters, but jQuery correctly follows the books here; Page 7, 2.2. Reserved Characters: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

Answer (score 0):

tack this on the end:

```
replace(/[&=]/g,'/').replace('?','')
```

like so:

```
url: function() {
  return (this.baseUrl + '?' + $.param({page: this.page, perPage: this.perPage})).replace(/[&=]/g,'/').replace('?','');
},
```

edited to point out in re to Felix Kling's concern about ?'s:
This will only remove the FIRST ? leaving any other ?'s that are part of the query string INTACT. Perfectly safe to use.

Comment: Right. I forgot that JavaScript is acting (for me) strange, concerning replacing characters... thanks for pointing that out again!